# How do I exclude Weekend days and get start date and end date

Tags: sql, datepart

Need help with a Start Date and End Date, that will NOT include Saturday and Sunday.

For example, if I run my query on Monday, my start date and end date will be:

1 = July 20th
2 = July 21st

[image: weekdays]

I'm tried this, in my Where clause, and get results. But not from Start Date and End Date range that I need:

```
((DATEPART(dw, [date_field]) + @@DATEFIRST) % 7) NOT IN (0, 1)
```

But, having issues with coding the StartDT (1) and EndDT (2) as shown on my screen shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE [date_field] BETWEEN [start_date] AND [end_date]
AND DATEPART(dw, [date_field]) NOT IN (6, 7)
```